# Issue with Rails Polymorphic Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to create an app for users to create a list of watches they own or wish to buy. I want users to be able to describe a lot of detail/attributes about their watches. I'm trying to create a parent/child association, but not using STI, as the children models have different data and I don't want a bunch of null values in my table.

I have 4 tables:

- users

  - Some user attributes
- watches

  - user_id
  - A bunch of attributes that are common to all watches, name, brand etc.
  - content_id
  - content_type
- mechanical_watches

  - Some attributes that only apply to mechanical watches
- quartz_watches

  - some attributes that only apply to quartz watches

**Models**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 include Clearance::User

 has_many :watches
end

class Watch < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :content, polymorphic: true
end

class MechanicalWatch < Watch
 has_one :watch, as: :content
end

class QuartzWatch < Watch
 has_one :watch, as: :content
end
```

I'm not a 100% sure if I've setup the associations correctly. But the problem I'm having is that when I enter MechanicalWatch into the console it returns only the attributes on Watch not any of the attributes in the mechanical_watches table. I've tried everything I can think of. Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using Rails 5, Ruby 2.3.1, and Postgres for the db.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want inheritance on `MechanicalWatch` or `QuartzWatch`. They appear to be separate tables from `Watch`. The relationship you show is `MechanicalWatch` "has a" `Watch`, instead of `MechanicalWatch` "is a" `Watch`.

You would change

`class MechanicalWatch < Watch`

to

`class MechanicalWatch`

Comment: Ok, that sorta makes sense. Maybe `MechanicalWatch` shouldn't "has a" `Watch`? `MechanicalWatch` is a type of `Watch`. Either way I changed to  `class QuartzWatch < ApplicationRecord` and `class MechanicalWatch < ApplicationRecord`, however now in the console instead of only getting the parent `Watch` attributes, now I only get the `MechanicalWatch` attributes when I run `MechanicalWatch.new`.

Comment: That sounds right based on the way you have it setup. Since the belongs_to is on the Watch, the foreign key to MechanicalWatch is stored on the Watch. MechanicalWatch likely has no fields stored directly on it yet. It just has a reference to Watch.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to be able to create a mechanical_watch instance, but still have the ability to set the fields on the watch model.

I.e. MechanicalWatch.new.field_on_watch = 4

If that's correct then u can look at this:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html

The pattern your looking for is delegation.

An important question to ask though: do you plan to use watches in a polymorphic way. I.e. Will u show all types of watches on the same page? Or will different watches be displayed separately?

Comment: I would like to display all watches together, and a watch can either be of type quartz or of type mechanical.

Comment: What does having that 'Type' get u?

Comment: Different types have different attributes. Quartz Watch has a set of attributes and mechanical watch has a different set of attributes. Watches has attributes that are common to both types.

Comment: They can have different attributes without being defined as a certain Type. What do u get from defining it as a type. What if u stored the extra attributes as a hash on a single Watch class?